# Show All Color Variants on Collection page in Shopify using Brooklyn Theme

Tags: collections, shopify, product, variants

Hey i am using brooklyn theme in my shopify website. I have different products will color variants . When i click on collection page i want to show all color variants of that products as separate products. I am googling since last night any help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the codes below.

```
<ul class="colorlist"> 
 {% for option in product.options %}
 {% if option == 'Color' %}
 {% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
 {% assign colorlist = '' %}
 {% assign color = '' %}
 {% for variant in product.variants %}
 {% capture color %}
 {{ variant.options[index] }}
 {% endcapture %}

 {% unless colorlist contains color %}
  {% if variant.available %}

  <li id="{{ variant.id }}" title="{{ variant.inventory_quantity }} In Stock" class="instock"><a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}?variant={{ variant.id }}" style="background:{{ color | downcase }}">{{ color | downcase }}</a></li>

  {% else %}

  <li id="{{ variant.id }}" title="Out of Stock"  class="outstock" >{{ color | downcase }}</li>

  {% endif %}

{% capture tempList %}
{{colorlist | append: color | append: " " }}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign colorlist = tempList %}
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The code above can display the available colors of a product in collection page. You can take the same loop structure and display the entire product grid instead of just displaying the variant name.

Comment: in which file do i use this ?

Comment: Can you help me with displaying the entire product grid?

Comment: I would love to help. If you are using the grid layout. You need to edit the Snippets/product-grid-item.liquid . Here is the code to place. [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/projoomexperts/793ee84852ff1528d8f051a08e954213/raw/fbbbe490303bf5c084eb3f1887cfb983eaf2f58a/product-grid-item.liquid)

Comment: I have tested before i gave you the codes, You can see the demo here.  http://price-match.myshopify.com/collections/all

Comment: Thank you man you saved the day. Every thing is working perfectly but now on home page the featured products are also showing its variants.How to restrict it.

Comment: Hi, Add a new snippet named 'product-grid-item-home.liquid'  now insert these codes in it.  [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/projoomexperts/6d4e602d5d94b52f62a3ee0fcefb7ffa/raw/9a51bbd879cf782c9e6d6de6dc9837d39fbbb4cf/product-grid-item-home.liquid)  and save it.

Now edit the snippet named 'featured-products.liquid' , Change line 57 from 
`{% include 'product-grid-item' %}`   to  `{% include 'product-grid-item-home' %}`

Save it. This should solve your problem with homepage.